# VisualStudio Code wrong Typescript Version in Runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8

I recently updated to VSCode 1.6.1 and it switched from Typescript 1.8.10 to 2.0.3, which has made my project to stop working.

The Reflect methods have changed so now Routing-Controllers is throwing the following error when trying to get a method attributes:

```
TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
   at exports.Body (C:\FN\FantasyNation\Stormbringer\node_modules\routing-contr
ollers\decorator\params.js:155:30)
   at __param (C:\FN\FantasyNation\Stormbringer\Scripts\controllers\UserControl
ler.js:12:37)
   at __decorate (C:\FN\FantasyNation\Stormbringer\Scripts\controllers\UserCont
roller.js:5:110)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\FN\FantasyNation\Stormbringer\Scripts\controllers\
UserController.js:56:1)
```

Following the instructions on the release notes to switch back to a specific version in my workspace I installed old typescript in the workspace:

```
npm install typescript@1.8.10
```

When reopening VSCode didn't ask me about the version of TS to use, so I manually updated my workspace "settings.json" to specify it:

```
{    
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js.map": true,
        "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "editor.stablePeek": true,
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

When I open a ".ts" file VSCode shows the right version:

[image]

But after rebuilding (ctrl+shift+B) and running it again (F5) I am still getting the exact same error.

My tsconfig is:

```
{ 
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6",
       "module": "commonjs",        
       "noImplicitAny": false,
       "removeComments": true,        
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,  
       "inlineSourceMap": true,
       "watch": false
   },
   "exclude": [
       "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

And my launch settings are:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5959
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a merge which messed up the code and moved the import order.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

Should be the first import to get routing-controllers working